# All CacheItems are being removed from MemoryCache at the same time

Tags: c#, memorycache

I am trying to add items to MemoryCache, when adding each item is accompanied by CacheItemPolicy with SlidingExpiration set to 3 seconds.

According to the documentation for SlidingExpiration:

> A span of time within which a cache entry must be accessed before the
> cache entry is evicted from the cache. The default

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.slidingexpiration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Based on the above I would expect that each individual item would be evicted after 3 seconds from being added (provided it has not been accessed or modified).

Instead, I notice that all items are being evicted at the same time. I would expect them to be evicted one by one.

I use the following code:
-creating memory cache:

```
_cache = new MemoryCache("My cache");
```

- adding items to cache:

  ```
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = new CacheItem(_i.ToString(), _i);
        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy()
        {
            SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3),
            RemovedCallback = MyRemovedCallback
        };

        _cache.Set(item, policy);
        _i++;
    }
  ```

What am I doing something wrong (I use .Net Framework 4.6.2 but also tested it on 4.8)?

Comment: "*Instead, I notice that all items are being evicted at the same time.*" -- how are you observing this? Is this using `MyRemovedCallback`? What do you do which triggers the removal?

Comment: I just added a label on the view and within MyRemovedCallback is set it's contents to the cachedItem.key and DateTime.Now. 
I do not trigger the removal in any way. I just wait to see until 3 seconds have passed. As mentioned, I would expect the items to be removed after 3 seconds from the time they are added.

Comment: I'm still not exactly clear on what you're seeing. Do note that the `MemoryCache` will not remove stale items unless you interact with it -- it's not using a timer or background thread to remove items periodically. Perhaps this explains what you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, that would explain the behavior. 
I was expecting that the stale items (the ones that were not interacted with for more than 3 seconds) would be removed on their own. 
Is there any way I can use MamoryCache to achieve that?